# Sub Query Returns More Than 1 Value

Tags: t-sql

I am getting error Sub Query Returns more than 1 value
here is my Query

```
SELECT d.Description ,s.Version , d.UtiPrefix , d.UTI , d.PrimaryAC , s.ReportingObb , s.ReportingObb , d.LEI , d.LEI_Countp  , d.LEI  , s.ReportingDeleg ,d.Curr , c.Trade_Party_Domicile ,c.LEI_SGR 
       , Price =( select Price 
                  From Price 
                  inner join Derivatives 
                  on Derivatives.UTI = Price.UTI)
FROM Derivatives as d
INNER JOIN Settings as  s
ON d.LEI_SGR  = s.LEI_SGR
INNER JOIN Clients c
ON d.LEI_SGR = c.LEI_SGR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery

```
Price =( select Price From Price p WHERE d.UTI = p.UTI)
```

Comment: I think you have the where backwards

Comment: @Blam It does not matter

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this returns more than one row

```
( select Price 
  From Price 
  inner join Derivatives 
  on Derivatives.UTI = Price.UTI )
```

why are you mixing sub queries with joins?

```
SELECT d.Description ,s.Version , d.UtiPrefix , d.UTI , d.PrimaryAC , s.ReportingObb 
     , s.ReportingObb , d.LEI , d.LEI_Countp  , d.LEI  , s.ReportingDeleg ,d.Curr 
     , c.Trade_Party_Domicile ,c.LEI_SGR 
     , p.Price
FROM Derivatives as d
INNER JOIN Settings as  s
   ON d.LEI_SGR  = s.LEI_SGR
INNER JOIN Clients c
   ON d.LEI_SGR = c.LEI_SGR
INNER JOIN Price p
   ON p.UTI = d.UTI
```